# How to Add Matrix and Chart in Word using office js

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, cpu-word

I am creating a word plugin through office API.I have some data

> [[2444],[266]]

(Array of Array)I want to represent this data in matrix.I also  want to create a chart but there is no Chart API available, is there any workaround to do so ?.Please help